# Case Statement in Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, case

I am trying to run the below query but keep having an issue with people whom have both requirements in my `Case` statement being pulled out for each instance when i only want a single record to be pulled, even if they have both conditions.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SyCampus.Descrip AS 'Campus',
    dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.instructorname AS 'Instructor Name',
    dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.classcode AS 'Class Code',
    dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.section AS 'Section',
    dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.classdescrip AS 'Class',
    RTRIM(SyStudent.FirstName) + ' ' + ' '  + RTRIM(SyStudent.LastName) AS 'Student Name',
    dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.stunum AS 'Student Number',
    CASE WHEN  CmEvent.CmtemplateID IN (714, 716, 732,734)THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END  AS 'Instructor Contact'


FROM 
    dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw
 JOIN
    SyStudent
        ON SyStudent.SyStudentID = dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.SyStudentID
 JOIN
    SyCampus
        ON Sycampus.SycampusID = SyStudent.SyCampusID
 JOIN
    CmEvent
        ON CmEvent.SyStudentID = SyStudent.SyStudentID

WHERE   dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.AttMin = '0'
    AND dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.date = DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()), 0) -1
    AND SyStudent.SySchoolStatusID IN (13, 129, 130, 132, 72, 59, 122, 14)
    AND dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.attendtype <> 'E'
    AND CmEvent.CmEventStatusid = '2'
```

Comment: What's the dialect? Microsoft's SQL Server? Other?

Comment: That `CASE` will never duplicate your rows - it will give back either yes or no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have a one-to-many relationship between SyStudent and CmEvent. Given that each SyStudent may have a corresponding CmEvent both in and out of the list (714, 716, 732,734) would explain why your query may return more than one record per SyStudent. If you'd like to know if a  SyStudent has a CmEvent.CmtemplateID  in the given list or not you can handle it in the join.

Consider the following changes to your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SyCampus.Descrip AS 'Campus',
    dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.instructorname AS 'Instructor Name',
    dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.classcode AS 'Class Code',
    dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.section AS 'Section',
    dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.classdescrip AS 'Class',
    RTRIM(SyStudent.FirstName) + ' ' + ' '  + RTRIM(SyStudent.LastName) AS 'Student Name',
    dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.stunum AS 'Student Number',
    CASE WHEN CmEvent.SyStudentID THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END  AS 'Instructor Contact'
    FROM 
    dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw 
JOIN
    SyStudent
        ON SyStudent.SyStudentID = dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.SyStudentID
 JOIN
    SyCampus
        ON Sycampus.SycampusID = SyStudent.SyCampusID
 LEFT JOIN
    CmEvent
        ON CmEvent.SyStudentID = SyStudent.SyStudentID 
        AND CmEvent.CmEventStatusid = '2'
        AND CmEvent.CmtemplateID IN (714, 716, 732,734)
WHERE   dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.AttMin = '0'
    AND dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.date = DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()), 0) -1
    AND SyStudent.SySchoolStatusID IN (13, 129, 130, 132, 72, 59, 122, 14)
    AND dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.attendtype <> 'E'
```

The two significant changes here are the left join and the case statement. Firstly, we've moved the CmEvent criteria into the left join. By doing this we will only join to records in the CmEvent that meets our criteria. This will leave out all of the CmEvent records whose template ID's are outside of our list. Secondly, the case statement is changed. Now we are using the existence of a CmEvent.SyStudentID to determine if the SyStudent has a CmEvent.CmtemplateID  in the given list. If the left join produces no match then know they do not.

Comment: +1 Not bad for a first answer :)  I was about to write something similar.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you want an outer aggregate query returning max('Instructor Contact').

Also, consider using 1 instead of 'yes' and 0 instead of 'no'

also, consider using table aliases.

Answer (score 1):

the `case` is effectively replacing one of these numbers 714, 716, 732,734 with either Yes or No so it *will* look like duplication but it's doing what you are asking of it. I think if you `GROUP BY` all the `SELECT` fields you should have distinct results.

Have a look in here on [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/360c0/5)

So you could do this:

```
   SELECT 
        SyCampus.Descrip AS 'Campus',
        dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.instructorname AS 'Instructor Name',
        dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.classcode AS 'Class Code',
        dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.section AS 'Section',
        dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.classdescrip AS 'Class',
        RTRIM(SyStudent.FirstName) + ' ' + ' '  + RTRIM(SyStudent.LastName) AS 'Student Name',
        dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.stunum AS 'Student Number',
        CASE WHEN  CmEvent.CmtemplateID IN (714, 716, 732,734)THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END  AS 'Instructor Contact'


    FROM 
        dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw
     JOIN
        SyStudent
            ON SyStudent.SyStudentID = dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.SyStudentID
     JOIN
        SyCampus
            ON Sycampus.SycampusID = SyStudent.SyCampusID
     JOIN
        CmEvent
            ON CmEvent.SyStudentID = SyStudent.SyStudentID

    WHERE   dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.AttMin = '0'
        AND dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.date = DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()), 0) -1
        AND SyStudent.SySchoolStatusID IN (13, 129, 130, 132, 72, 59, 122, 14)
        AND dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.attendtype <> 'E'
        AND CmEvent.CmEventStatusid = '2'
   GROUP BY
        SyCampus.Descrip,
        dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.instructorname,
        dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.classcode,
        dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.section,
        dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.classdescrip,
        RTRIM(SyStudent.FirstName) + ' ' + ' '  + RTRIM(SyStudent.LastName),
        dbo.rpt_adAttendanceDetail_vw.stunum,
        CASE WHEN  CmEvent.CmtemplateID IN (714, 716, 732,734)THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END
```

On a small query there's probably not much to gain but I think `GROUP BY` is preferable to `DISTINCT` in terms of performance: [reference here](http://forums.teradata.com/forum/enterprise/distinct-vs-group-by-insert-vs-create-as)